# I do not know how this works. @Input() in Angular

Tags: angular

Good morning. I do not know how @Input () works as the title suggests.

In many examples, we saw the use of

```
@Input() inputArgument:any;
```

I searched to find a grammatical definition of @Input.

In directives.d.ts, The definition of Input is as follows.

```
export interface Input {
    /**
     * Name used when instantiating a component in the template.
     */
    bindingPropertyName?: string;
}
```

First of all. How does the at sign(@) symbol work?

I learned an example of Interface as follows.

```
interface InterfaceTest {
  dataOne: string,
  dataTwo?: string
}

class implTest implements InterfaceTest{
  dataOne = 'impleSuccess';
}
```

But, despite the same interface, why does the (Input) have an at sign(@)?

Second, how [@Input () something:anytype] code assigned to bindingPropertyName in interface Input?

thank you!

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/Input, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction, https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives What could someone explain that the documentation does cover extensively yet?

Comment: You searched in `directives.d.ts` but did you read the documentation?

Comment: have a look at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: ou... thank you guys. I am studying only the book and the sample code attached to this book. sorry. I will study the reference site in the future. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, `@Input()` defines a input binding, connected to your components selector.

When using your selector in another components Html you can adress this variable by:

```
<your-component-selector [yourInputVariable]="'test'"></your-component-selector>
```

In the `your-component-selector` component you define the Input as follows:

```
Import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'your-component-selector',
    templateUrl: './your.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss']
})

export class YourComponent {
    @Input('yourInputVariable')
    inputVariable: string;        //<-- this will result to 'test'
}
```

Read the tutorial https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding for further information!